# checking for no rows after calling a stored procedure using php pdo to a mysql database columnCount not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
    $sql = "CALL pr_cartItemsForCustomer (:customerId)";        
    $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);    
    $statement->bindValue(':customerId',$customerId);
    $statement->execute();

    if($statement->columnCount() > 0)
```

This always returns 5 columns even when there are no rows returned, what is the proper way to check for no rows? I tried rowCount but that did not work.

The code works OK for a query but not when calling a stored procedure that returns a query.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to find out the number of rows returned is to use [`count()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) on the returned PHP array.

```
$sql = "CALL pr_cartItemsForCustomer (:customerId)";        
$statement = $connection->prepare($sql);    
$statement->bindValue(':customerId',$customerId);
$statement->execute();
$results = $statement->fetchAll();

echo count($results);
```

However, please note that your example does not need it at all. If all you want is to check for any returned rows then just use the array itself as a boolean value. e.g. `if($results)` Read more at https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#count

```
$results = $statement->fetchAll();

if($results) {
    foreach($result as $row) {
        // ...
    }
} else {
    echo 'No records!';
}
```

Comment: I was using while ($row = $statement->fetch (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))

Comment: Why? The statement is traversable in the first place, you do not need a while/fetch loop

Comment: so you mean something like: $results = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$num_rows = count($results);

foreach($results as $row) {
//
}

Comment: Yes, that is more or less what I have in my answer.

Comment: OK, although some people seem to think its not so good to fetch all the rows in one go. Thanks for your help. t-sql has a simple sqlsrv_has_rows function.

Comment: You are fetching them either way, so what is the difference? For PHP to count them, either through `count()` or through `rowCount()` you need to have all records fetched from the database.

Comment: I only needed to know if the result set was empty